# Binding в тригер

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Как можно привязать данные к свойствам doubleanimation. А то при запуске сразу вылетает.

```
<DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Left)" From="{Binding Size}" To="{Binding EndSize}" 
                                             Duration="{Binding Time}" RepeatBehavior="Forever"/>



<Style TargetType="TextBlock" x:Key="RunningLine">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{Binding ModelsRunLine.RunLineColor}" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="55"/>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ModelsRunLine.IsActive}" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
            <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Left)" From="1920" To="-1920" 
                                             Duration="0:0:05" RepeatBehavior="Forever"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ModelsRunLine.IsActive}" Value="false">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: InvalidOperationException: Не удается зафиксировать данное дерево шкалы времени Storyboard для использования в различных потоках.

Comment: Вы хотите что бы ваш элемент `TextBlock` переместился из одного положения в другое?

Comment: @sp7 Да, хочу сделать бегущую стркоу

Comment: А при каких условиях она должна у вас запускаться?

Comment: @sp7 Условие читается из базы, а хочу чтобы в зависимости от размера текста параметры расставлять.

Comment: Так у вас ругается на то, что вы данные изменяете в другом потоке. Воспользуйтесь `Dispatcher`

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать так:

1) Воспользуемся AttachedProperty, реализация которого предложена ([@VladD](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/10105/vladd))

```
public static class AnimatableDoubleHelper
{
    // Это attached property OriginalProperty. К нему мы будем привязывать свойство из VM,
    // и получать нотификацию об его изменении
    public static double GetOriginalProperty(DependencyObject obj) =>
        (double)obj.GetValue(OriginalPropertyProperty);
    public static void SetOriginalProperty(DependencyObject obj, double value) =>
        obj.SetValue(OriginalPropertyProperty, value);
    public static readonly DependencyProperty OriginalPropertyProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "OriginalProperty", typeof(double), typeof(AnimatableDoubleHelper),
            new PropertyMetadata(OnOriginalUpdated));

    // это "производное" attached property, которое будет
    // анимированно "догонять" OriginalProperty
    public static double GetAnimatedProperty(DependencyObject obj) =>
        (double)obj.GetValue(AnimatedPropertyProperty);
    public static void SetAnimatedProperty(DependencyObject obj, double value) =>
        obj.SetValue(AnimatedPropertyProperty, value);
    public static readonly DependencyProperty AnimatedPropertyProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "AnimatedProperty", typeof(double), typeof(AnimatableDoubleHelper));

    // это вызывается когда значение OriginalProperty меняется
    static void OnOriginalUpdated(DependencyObject o, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        double newValue = (double)e.NewValue;
        // находим элемент, на котором меняется свойство
        FrameworkElement self = (FrameworkElement)o;
        DoubleAnimation animation = // создаём анимацию...
            new DoubleAnimation(newValue, new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.3)));
        // и запускаем её на AnimatedProperty
        self.BeginAnimation(AnimatedPropertyProperty, animation);
    }
}
```

2) Создаем простейшую разметку окна

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:viewModel="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1.ViewModel"
        xmlns:wpfApplication4="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Canvas Grid.Row="0">
            <!-- Используем наше AttachedProperty -->
            <TextBlock Canvas.Left="{Binding (wpfApplication1:AnimatableDoubleHelper.AnimatedProperty), RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
                       wpfApplication1:AnimatableDoubleHelper.OriginalProperty="{Binding Value}"
                       Text="Текст" />
        </Canvas>
        <Button Grid.Row="1" Command="{Binding DoCommand}" Content="Тыц" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

3) Создаем ViewModel, в которой будем изменять свойство `Value`.

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public RelayCommand DoCommand { get; set; }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        DoCommand = new RelayCommand(() =>
        {
            // В зависимости от наших условий измененяем значение свойства.
            Value = Value == 100 ? 0 : 100;
        });
    }
}
```